# update doesn't work

Tags: php, sql-update

I've been trying to update a table in my database triggered by an UPDATE button but somehow it doesn't work, whenever I change the values then click the update button, it just refreshes the values, no update/change happens..please help

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbconnect.php");

$webhost=$_GET["webhost"];

$requesttitle=$_POST["requesttitle"];
$requesturl=$_POST["requesturl"];
$requestcap=$_POST["requestcap"];
$requestdestype=$_POST["requestdestype"];
$requestdbtype=$_POST["requestdbtype"];
$deptname=$_POST["deptname"];
$contactname=$_POST["contactname"];
$contactnum=$_POST["contactnum"];
$contactemail=$_POST["contactemail"];
$startdate=$_POST["startdate"];
$enddate=$_POST["enddate"];

if(isset($_POST['button']))
{

$sql="update webhostrequest set requesttitle='$requesttitle', ";
    $sql.="requesturl='$requesturl', requestcap='$requestcap', ";
    $sql.="requestdestype='$requestdestype', requestdbtype='$requestdbtype', ";
    $sql.="deptname='$deptname', contactname='$contactname', ";
    $sql.="contactnum='$contactnum', contactemail='$contactemail' ';
    $sql.="startdate='$startdate',  enddate='$enddate', recentact=now() where requestid='$id'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error in editing item. ".mysql_error());
}
header("location: editwebhost.php?webhost=$webhost");
exit;

?>
```

Comment: I long for the day when all PHP-SQL questions in SO are using parametrized queries :(

Comment: By the way, this line is wrong:  $sql.="contactnum='$contactnum', contactemail='$contactemail' ';
It should be:  $sql.="contactnum='$contactnum', contactemail='$contactemail', ";

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, i seem to have made a typographical error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$id is not set in your code. So as the "WHERE" stipulates only update the entry with requestid =$id, it's probably the missing link?

Comment: i'm sorry, i've overlooked this part, it should be requestid='$webhost'

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing $sql to the page so you can see what query your code is producing. Then try running the query directly (through phpMyAdmin or however you access your db).

Are you getting any error from your "or die()"?